# How can i unlock Golden Dice from the casino vendor?

Tags: tales-of-xillia-2

In *Tales of Xillia 2* a number of guides show the use of Golden Dice in order to obtains large amount of Poker Chips to farm Friendship Potions for Affinity raising, items for selling to clear the debt and for getting a trophy associated with collecting 100,000 Poker Chips.

According to a bunch if [guides](https://www.neoseeker.com/tales-of-xillia-2/faqs/892949-b.html#h88) and the [guide for getting the trophy](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/tales-of-xillia-2/trophy/90639-Gambler.html) you can buy Golden Dice from the casino vendor. i've just completed the part where

> the Fractured Dimension Milla sacrificed herself and the Prime Milla as returned

but when i check the casino vendor i can't buy Golden Dice.

How do i unlock Golden Dice from the casino vendor?

Comment: I don't recall when these become available at the casino vendor... it's been a bit too long since I've played this. But I do remember that buying dice from the casino vendor isn't the most efficient way to gather them, as I think they are in very limited supply there.. You can get them on a pretty consistent basis from the first floors of the EX dungeon (end game).